# Use image in place of <button id>

Tags: html, image, button

http://protected-river-1861.herokuapp.com/

I've tried various codes but not seem to work, at best I get an 'image not found.'

```
<button id="go-search">Go!</button>
```

I have inserted the button into my public/images folder, and I just need to tell the code to load it up.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you have more code? It seems to me that you should look some basic tutorials of html and php before doing this.

Comment: Seems to be loading all fine for me. Did "Makers Academy" get mean or something?

Comment: I don't study there, it's part of a free tutorial they have provided.  I'm a complete and utter beginner here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css like this?

```
#go-search {
    background: url("/images/logo.gif") no-repeat;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```